# Limit of $u(x):=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{f(y)}{|x-y|^{n-2}}\; dy.$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f\in C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $n\ge 3$, be a compact support function. We consider $u(x):=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{f(y)}{|x-y|^{n-2}}\; dy.$

How can I prove that $u(x)\to 0,\quad\text{for}\; |x|\to\infty$?

Comment: Here's a hint: if the support of $f$ is compact, it can fit within a ball $B=\{y: |y| \leq R\}$ of radius $R$ centered at the origin. Then, if $|x| \geq N$, you have $|x-y| \geq N-R$ for $y \in B$.

Comment: @Sambo Thanks but I don't understand. Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the support $S$ of $f$ is a compact of $\mathbb{R}^n$, it is in particular bounded. Therefore, there exists a closed ball $B$ centered at $0$ of radius $R$ and such that $S\subset B$. Now you can divide your integral into twi parts : the integral $I_1(x)$ on the ball $B$ and the integral $I_2 (x)$ on $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus B$, which is 0.
Since $f$ is continuous with compact support, it is bounded by $M\in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$. Therefore, for $\vert x\vert := L \geq 2R$, you get
$$u(x)=I_1(x) \leq M \int_{B} \frac{1}{\vert x-y\vert ^{n-2}} dy$$

Now, since $\vert x-y\vert \geq L-R>0$ for any $y\in B$, we finally get
$$u(x)\leq M \int_{B} \frac{dy}{(L-R)^{n-2}}= M\text{vol}(B)(L-R)^{2-n}$$
which tends to $0$ when $L=\vert x \vert \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Thanks! A last question: Your inequality holds for $|u(x)|$ too?

Comment: You are welcome. And yes, just take the absolute value in the inequality.